# Javascript: Appending to element makes previous children lose input data

Tags: javascript, html

The button `onClick` function in the example below adds textareas one below another. But, the problem is when I add for example 2 textareas and type some text in it, and then add the third textarea - the text I typed before is gone. It is refreshed and blank, it isn't saved.

Is there a solution? Or maybe some other more sophisticated method.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/2/)

**index.html**

```
<input type="submit" value="ADD" onClick="add();">
<div id="new"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
n=1;
function add() {
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML += '<div>' + n + '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/></div>';
n++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOM APIs to append the `<div>` instead of setting `innerHTML`.

```
var n = 1;
function add() {
  var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.name = "question" + n;
  textarea.rows = 4;
  textarea.cols = 50;

  var div = document.createElement("div");    
  div.innerHTML = n + ". Question: <br />" + textarea.outerHTML + "<br />";

  document.getElementById("new").appendChild(div);
  n++;
}
```

It is quite longer, but has much less string concatenation - so it's way easier to read. If it gets more complicated than that, you might want to consider using a templating language such as Mustache or Handlebars.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/6/

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` will not capture the user input.  You will need to make the new elements instead, leaving the old markup in place.

```
n=1;
function add() {
    var container = document.getElementById("new");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = n + ". Question: <br/>";
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "question" + n;
    textarea.rows = 4;
    textarea.cols = 50;
    div.appendChild(textarea);
    container.appendChild(div);        
    n++;        
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/7/

Comment: You missed the final `<br />` after the `<textarea>` ;) (not that it makes any difference)

Comment: @RenatoZannon I don't think its necessary `div` is a block level element and will be put on a new line.  If you compare the OP's original fiddle to mine there is no vertical space difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't, but it is on the OP. Nevermind though, I was just picking on your answer because it's very similar to mine ;)

Comment: Its all good, I was just glad I could remember how to write some native JS without jQuery.

Comment: I was confused by "`innerHTML will not capture the user input`" I think saying "`innerHTML` does not reflect changes to the state of the element" may make it clearer. It doesn't reflect any changes, not just  user input. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/7BEH5/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated Fiddle. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/5/)

```
function add() {
    $('#new').append('<div>' + n + '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/></div>');
    n++; 
}
```

Edit: I did add jQuery as it's simply easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS answer which gets rid of the global add() function and the 'n' variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/qV6jd/4/

```
<input type="submit" value="ADD" id='addButton'>
<div id="new"></div>

document.getElementById('addButton')
   .onclick = function () {
   pDiv = document.getElementById('new');
   var n = pDiv.childNodes.length + 1;
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.innerHTML = n + '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question' + n + '" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/>';
   pDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are working solutions here. However, I don't feel they are really explaining the problem.

When you have code like

```
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML += 
    '<div>' +n+ '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4"cols="50">' +
    '</textarea><br/></div>';
```

You may be tempted to think that you are appending to the HTML, but you are not. You are completely overwriting the html inside your `#new`. It's the same as setting

```
var div = document.getElementById('new');
div.innerHTML +=  div.innerHTML + 
    '<div>' +n+ '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4"cols="50">' +
    '</textarea><br/></div>';
```

One would expect the `innerHTML` to contain the current values in the `textareas` , but it doesn't, [it contains the value of the node when it was created initially](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/7BEH5/).

You have to use DOM manipulation to append the textareas without affecting existing ones [as others have suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22366617/227299)